# How can I debug python web site on amazon EC2?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to web development. This is probably a dumb question but I could not quite find exact answer or tutorial that could help me. The company I am working at has its site(which is built in python django )hosted on amazon EC2. I want to know where I can start about debugging this production site and check logs and databases that are stored there. I have the account information but is there anyway I can access all the stuff using command line(like an ubuntu shell) or tutorial for the same ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to find out where your code is located on the server.  SSH to one of the instances and then you can use the python interactive shell to run your django code for debugging, use the manage.py commands for database debugging, tests etc.

Once you have connected to the instance, it's just an OS.