# Cannot Debug Django using pdb

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, pdb

I am trying to add a `breakpoint()` to a particular line in a `Django` code which is running on an `ec2 instance`. I have tried `ipdb`, `pdb`

tried
`import pdb;set_trace()`
it quits giving a `BdbQuit` error.

tried simply adding
`breakpoint`

This simply gets ignored

None of them stop the code. If I run the code like this

`python -m pdb manage.py runserver` ,

it immediately drops into `pdb` and fails after executing 2 lines. How exactly should I use `pdb` in `Django` correctly?

Old answers don't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BdbQuit raised when debugging Python with pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914704/bdbquit-raised-when-debugging-python-with-pdb)

Comment: @NKSM Provides an explanation for why it doesn't work. The program is running in the background..ok...but then what to do to debug? That part I cannot see.

Comment: Another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407554/how-can-i-debug-python-web-site-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48719897/6759844